# Using Codeblocks for step by step execution of my code

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I remember there was shortcut key <kbd>F8</kbd> in Turbo C that showed step by step execution of the code, and it also let you to see the values of the variables.

**Is something similar available for Codeblocks?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code::blocks provide the debugging feature. We can watch the values of variables and execute step by step.

1. Create the project
2. Add the break point by right click the mouse at the line number where you want and choose Toggle Break point.
3. Click on Debug menu and form debugging windows option select watches window.

In watches window you can see the values of variable and for step by step execution after break point use shift+F7 key.

My answer may not be clear for you or for further information you can follow this codeblocks wiki page http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks